# Timestamp of the last Full-GC

Tags: prometheus, promql, garbage

Is there a Query in Prometheus, that would let me know at what point the last Full-GC occured?

I know there are queries that let me know the number of GC runs/s, but I am in need of the exact timestamp of the last Full-GC.